# Magento 1.9 can't find topLinks block

Tags: magento-1.9, topmenu

I'm using Porto theme (documentation: [porto doc](http://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/documentation/)) and i want to change to topLinks:

[image]

The problem is that i can't find the static block that contains those links. Or are those links inside a `.phtml` file? :-s

Thank you!

Comment: you can find above header links in custmer.xml file where you can remove or change the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Admin > Port > Porto - Settings Panel > Header Type` you find your selected header type.

In that selected type `Header 3` for exemple you'll find : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks'); ?>`, this `topLinks` refers to `customer.xml` and that links are added via xml something like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

To find the path's you have to enable the path hints like [this](https://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints).

Comment: hey @PRINCE, i don't have a customer.xml in my layout folder :(

Comment: You copy it from `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` to `app/design/frontend/smartwave/{themename}/layout/customer.xml` then update this last one

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank youuuuuuuu! :D it works <3

Comment: Lol :) you're welcome, Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the top links do not come from PHTML files or static blocks.

These links appear from the layout XML files of the theme.

Below is the default place where you can find these links:

- **My Account:** app/design/frontend/{your-theme-package}/{your-theme}/layout/customer.xml
- **Log In:** app/design/frontend/{your-theme-package}/{your-theme}/layout/customer.xml
- **My Wishlist:** app/design/frontend/{your-theme-package}/{your-theme}/layout/wishlist.xml

You can find code like below:

```
<reference name="top.links">
...
...
</reference>
```

**Update:** Remove Log In link from the top links:

```
<customer_logged_out>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

Find the code like above and either **comment out** or **remove it** from the **app/design/frontend/{your-theme-package}/{your-theme}/layout/customer.xml** file.

Comment: hey, thank you for taking time off to help me but how do i choose to eliminate "Log In" for example? :-? I want to have only My Account and My Wishlist there :(

Comment: @emma, please check my updated answer.

Comment: hey, i don't have a `customer.xml` file in there :(

Comment: then there should a **local.xml** file, where you can find such code.